Generate wildcard cert and install on all current and future IIS sites with win-acme
Surprisingly, I cannot find a simple explanation how to create a wildcard certificate and install it on multiple IIS sites, current and future. Many things in the documentation suggest this might be possible.
However, it appears that I need to use the manual source to get a wildcard cert, and then I have to specify the installation plugin as iis. But, the installation plugin seems to want me to specify a installationsiteid or it just fails.
I have tried this:
wacs --source manual --host *.mydomain.com --installation iis --installationsiteid 25 --validation route53 --route53accesskeyid <mykey> --route53secretaccesskey <mysecret> --accepttos --emailaddress admin@mydomain.com --verbose --test

This works and installs the certificate on a single site. How can I get win-acme to create a wildcard certificate from Lets Encrypt and install it on all current and future IIS sites?
